# Default constructor argument in custom markup extensions

Tags: xaml, winui-3, winui

I've got a custom `MarkupExtension` `FooBinding`.

```cs
public class FooBinding : MarkupExtension
{
    public PropertyPath Path { get; set; }

    public FooBinding(string path)
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(path);
    }

    public FooBinding()
    {
    }
}
```

that would work:

```xml
<MyControl MyProperty="{foo:FooBinding Path=MyViewModel.MyViewModelProperty}"/>
```

that's not working and I'm getting the following error message:

```xml
<MyControl MyProperty="{foo:FooBinding MyViewModel.MyViewModelProperty}"/>
```

> WMC061: Type 'foo' used after '{' must be a Markup Extensions. Error code 0x09d7

In `wpf` it was possible to use `ConstructorArgumentAttribute` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.constructorargumentattribute). Is there an equivalent for `winUI` ?